# Extending Bootstrap 5 card to bottom of screen goes off screen

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm using BS 5 (latest) and have set up a two column page.   In the right column, I added a card which I want to extend to the bottom of page.

There is padding at the top and bottom of the card.

I added vh-100 to the card but the issue is that the card goes past the bottom of the screen, causing the scrollbar to appear.  If the padding is removed, it works, but the top and bottom borders of the card are not visible.

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      Menu system
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="card vh-100 mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          main content area
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

How can I make the card take up the entire space minus the padding constraints?

Comment: Please check your fiddle. Its totally blank. Updates it and post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
.card {
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem - 0.5rem) !important;
}
```

Set `height` to full-screen height, minus all the paddings and/or margins.

See the snippet below.

```css
.card {
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem - 0.5rem) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      Menu system
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
          main content area
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Perfect thanks!   So if I were to adjust the top/bottom margin/paddings, I would need to adjust the CSS  subtracted values?  Does 1rem apply to mt-2 and 8px to mb-3?

Comment: I edited my answer.  Yes, you can change `mt-2` to `mt-5`, for example. It's the opposite ( `1.5rem` is equal to `8px` in this case).